# Error when moving my project to MacBook Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: java, flutter, flutter-dependencies

any idea how to solve this ?

Thank you!

[image]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Users\JoinUser10\Desktop\Travelling flutter Androd\source\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\AssetManifest.json

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         7,7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Did you solve the problem with flutter.gradle' line: 991?

Comment: No, I just create a new project and moved all code to the new project

Comment: I fixed it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66625467/flutter-run-for-android-failed-flutter-gradle-line-991-finished-with-non-z

Answer (score 0):

Errors such this, will be solved by updating gradle version in most cases. In my case, the problem was that I cloned the project from repo and project was developed by my colleague months ago. So I solved the issue by updating gradle version in **gradle-wrapper.properties** file and also updating `tools.build:gradle` in **android/build.gradle** file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I Solved the problem using

```
    flutter clean
```

Then I used pub get
and everything worked smoothly