# flutter run for android failed - flutter.gradle' line: 991 - finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, gradle

After flutter upgrade flutter to newest stable version I can't debug in android simulator. I get the following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
```

lib/main.dart:1
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_webservice-0.0.19/lib/src/utils.dart:61:27: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.

- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  return httpClient.get(url, headers: headers);
  ^
  ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_webservice-0.0.19/lib/src/utils.dart:74:28: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
  return httpClient.post(url, body: body, headers: postHeaders);
  ^
  3

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/michael/Documents/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/michael/Documents/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Author of google_maps_webservice plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_webservice) does not release flutter 2.0.2 compatible version yet.
You can switch to 0.0.20-nullsafety.2 version (https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_webservice/versions/0.0.20-nullsafety.2)

add explicitly

```
google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.20-nullsafety.2
```

to dependencies in pubspec.yaml

Update the compileSdkVersion to 30 in my app/build.gradle

do not forget run:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Comment: Thank you very much! After inserting the dependency google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.20-nullsafety.2 and update the compileSdkVersion to 30 I just had to insert "Firebase.initializeApp()" in my main.dart and the android-emulator startet correctly. But I have problem with iOS simulator... 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4112 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, but after i move the folders to android studio projects folder it worked fine